# Two operators simultaneity overload in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to represent my object like an array. I mean that the programmer can write in his code

`myobject[3]=2`

In the back (in myobject code) there isn't an array at all, it's only representation.

So I need to overload `[]` and `=` simultaneously. 
How can this be done?

thank you,
and sorry about my poor English.

Comment: Give a bit detail about what your object stores and how the index values makes sense. Is it plain x, y, z? Are you creating the value for the index WHEN the index is being accessed?

Comment: I use vector as a private member. I use vector because I don't know the size of the array at the programming. But I want to give an access to every member in the vector. It's impossibly to give address of one member of vector,

Comment: Yes you give access to any member in the vector. Check my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`operator[]` should return a reference to object you are trying to modify. It may be some kind of metaobject, that overloads `operator=` to do whatever you wish with your main object.

**Edit**: As the OP clarified the problem, there *is* a way to do this. Look here:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int & func(std::vector<int> & a)
{
    return a[3];
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    a.push_back(4);
    func(a) = 111;
    std::cout << a[3] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Huh, I must have been asleep already. of course, you are right, IDK why I missed that...

Comment: Thank you Griwes. Sorry, but I don't understand how it's answer on my question. I asked about general object that overload `[]`, and you answer that _vector object_ has `[]`. I want to use my object not vector.

Comment: Yup, but i showed you, that if your `operator[]`, returning `int &`, will return `vector[i]`, then it will work. And, I really don't get why, after accepting answer saying the same thing as mine (when I propose a way to understand the code by you, not only copy it - without attacking anyone), you ask me _how this answers my question?_. It answers in the same way that the accepted one does.

Comment: Thank you Griwes. You right, it was mine lack of understanding, and I'll fix it.

Comment: @Griwes: Sorry I wasn't attacking you. You're code, before editing had a serious flaw in that you were using `return a.begin()+3`. This didn't do bounds check and hence would crash if the user asked for index 5 for example. I was merely letting the OP know what was wrong. I edited my answer as soon as I saw you made changes.

Comment: I know, neither I was attacking anyone.

Answer (score 4):

> So I need to overload [] and = simultaneity. How can it's can be done?

It can't be done. What you can do instead is override `operator[]` to return a 'proxy reference'. That is, an object that has knowledge of the object 'myobject' to which it was applied and the index used '3', and provides appropiate conversion operators to the mapped type (I pressume `int`) as well as assignment operators. There are a few examples of proxy references in the standard library itself. Something in the lines of:

```
class proxy
{
public:
    proxy( object& object, int index ) : _object( object ), _index( index ) {}

    operator int() const { return _object.implementation.value_at( index ); }

    proxy operator=( int value ){ _object.implementation.value_at( index, value ); return *this; }

private:
    object& _object;
    int _index;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

@yoni: It is possible to give address of any member of the vector (as long as it exists). Here's how it's done.

```
int& MyObject::operator[](size_t index)
{
    return mVector[index];
}
const int& MyObject::operator[](size_t index) const
{
    return mVector[index];
}
```

This is possible because std::vector is guaranteed to be storing elements in a contiguous array. The operator[] of std::vector returns a reference-type of the value it stores. By you overloading the operator[], you just need to pass that reference out of your operator[] function.

NOTE: std::vector will take care of bounds check. With the solution that @Griwes gives, there's no bounds checking.

EDIT: Seems like Griwes has edited his solution.